# Why do I have to add .to_i for Postgresql to know this field is an integer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

The following line works fine in MySQL, but in Postgresql I get a Rails error stating, "can't convert Fixnum to String".

```
viewable.update_attribute(:total_views, viewable.total_views.to_i + 1)
```

total_views is an integer field

Shouldn't Rails know to treat total_views as an integer even if I am using Postgresql?

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is "yes" Rails should know how to deserialize that column as an integer.  What version of Rails and what Postgres adapter are you using?

As a bonus, though, you can do the following to accomplish what you want:

```
viewable.increment(:total_views)
```

Comment: p = self.total_likes.to_i + self.total_comments.to_i * 2 Notice the .to_i methods I have to call. I am using Rails 2.3.4 on Heroku.

Comment: postgres (0.7.9.2008.01.28) is the gem installed in Heroku

Comment: When I removed the .to_i method calls and tested on MySQL it worked fine. But under Postgresql I get the error.

Comment: The fields are set to NOT NULL and DEFAULT 0

Comment: I'm surprised no one else has run into this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you would have the same problem with the

```
update_attributes
```

method. Since the

```
update_attribute
```

method skips Rails validations.Try using the former, and you may get a better picture on what's going on behind the scenes.

Comment: Not sure how validations would make a difference, but maybe they would invoke a show fields. I'll give it a try.